# Can't inject content script into YouTube

Tags: google-chrome

This question is more for the benefit of others and my own curiosity, as I have synthesized a workaround for now (using `"matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"]` and `if (location.hostname == "www.youtube.com")`.

Anyway, when I have an issue like this I break the code down into simpler and simpler forms until it starts to work. Then I can figure out what's tripping up the code. But I've hit that point now where it can't get simpler and it still doesn't work. Chrome just won't inject a content script into any of YouTube's pages.

**Files** ([link to ZIP of the following](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/27573003/Social%20Distribution/contentScript_YouTube.zip))

manifest.json:

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "version": "0",
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "content_scripts": [ 
        {
            "js": [
                "test.js"
            ],
            "matches": [
                "*://youtube.com/*"
            ],
            "run_at": "document_end",
            "all_frames": true
        }
    ]
}
```

test.js:

```
alert("test");
```

**Progress**

Doesn't work:

- Varying the values and statically defining (no wildcards) the `matches` URL
- Varying the values of `run_at`
- Varying the values of `all_frames`
- Varying the scripting in `test.js`
- Fresh install of Chrome v24.0.1312.57 on a fresh install of Windows 7 x64

Does work:

- Changing the `matches` value to ANYTHING other than YouTube
- Changing the `matches` value to `"http://*/*", "https://*/*"`

I feel like I'm missing something *really* obvious here, but it's been days.. ;/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me if you define the match in the manifest as "http://www.youtube.com/*"

Comment: *Facepalm*. Looks like I was missing something ridiculously obvious - I didn't know you HAD to enter `www.`. Thanks. :L